# Keycloak token not active with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have spring boot backend app with Angular js app. The login process and initial backend communication are successful. After some idle time, the front end will show 403 forbidden with token not active on the backend console.

The code below contains refresh token, But it seems not working.

```
// use bearer token when calling backend
themesApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  var isExpired = keycloak.isTokenExpired();
  var token = keycloak.token;

  if (isExpired) {
    keycloak.updateToken(5)
    .success(function() {
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'BEARER ' + token;
    })
    .error(function() {
      console.error('Failed to refresh token');
    });
  }

  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'BEARER ' + token;
}]);
```

Error on the backend

```
2017-05-29 10:08:23.715 ERROR 5072 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Failed to verify token

org.keycloak.common.VerificationException: Token is not active
```

Answer (score 1):

Something must be wrong on the Keycloak Server, *Token not active* means token being is expired or is used before it gets valid. Could it be that the time/date is wrong on your KC server ?

Comment: yeah, I checked on both keycloak server and client. They seem on correct time zone.

Comment: This can easily happen if running keycloak on WSL and you sleep or hibernate: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5324
Quick fix is `wsl --shutdown` from Powershell

Answer (score 1):

you can config the 'Session Idle Time' here:

[image]

I had the same issue and handle it with an automatical logout. So the user has to login again.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
var token = keycloak.token;
```

you define the value of token once. After the update you have to set it again:

```
// use bearer token when calling backend
themesApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  var isExpired = keycloak.isTokenExpired();
  var token = keycloak.token;

  if (isExpired) {
    keycloak.updateToken(5)
    .success(function() {

     // UPDATE THE TOKEN
     token = keycloak.token;

     $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'BEARER ' +     token;
    })
.error(function() {
  console.error('Failed to refresh token');
});
}

 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'BEARER ' + token;
}]);
```